# "Exception from Layer: 149" Problem with CoreML model after converting from PyTorch

Tags: ios, pytorch, coreml, onnx, onnx-coreml

I trained a YOLOv3-SPP model using PyTorch. I then saved it as an ONNX model and then converted it to CoreML using `onnx-coreml`. When I try to make a prediction using the model I get this error:

```
    YOLOv3-CoreML[13481:1004975] [espresso] [Espresso::handle_ex_plan] exception=Espresso exception: "Invalid state": reshape mismatching size: 13 13 24 1 1 -> 6 10 8 3 1 [Exception from Layer: 149: 300]
2020-03-16 13:46:05.248612-0500 YOLOv3-CoreML[13481:1004975] [coreml] Error computing NN outputs -1
```

This is the code I am using to make the prediction:

```
 if let prediction = try? model.prediction(input_1: image) {
      print("Output: \(prediction)")
    }
```

I did some digging to find layer #149. I used this script to find its name:

```
import coremltools
import numpy as np

mlmodel = coremltools.models.MLModel("model.mlmodel")
spec = mlmodel._spec

print(spec.neuralNetwork.layers[149])
```

I found its name to be "308". So I opened the model up in Netron and got this:

[image]

The layer in question is circled in red. How can I get my CoreML model to work properly?

Comment: Are you sure the input image size works with this model?

Comment: @Matthijs Hollemans I am pretty sure it is the right size. The model said 416 x 416 and that's what I am giving it.

Comment: It's possible that the conversion to ONNX had an error in it, or the conversion from ONNX to Core ML. Sometimes these conversion tools don't do the correct thing.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans what do you suggest that I do next in order to fix the issue?

Comment: What I would do in this case is convert the model up to the point where it gives the error. And then implement the rest in code. But it might also be possible to fix this in the model itself. (I'd need more information to give complete advice.)

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I have tested the onnx model and it works as intended. So something went wrong during the conversion from onnx to CoreML. What kind of info do you need in order to solve the issue or at least point me in right direction?

Comment: An issue like this will typically take me 1 - 3 hours to debug and fix, more if it requires implementing a portion of the model in code. That's not something I can do in a Stack Overflow answer.